# Jquery - Identify if radio button value has not changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to identify if the value of radio button has not changed?

Currently I am trying to change the confirmation message of submit button on button changed, and do not want any message if the value has not changed. I have something like this now:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
    var selected = $('input:checked[type="radio"]').val();
    if(selected == 'true') {
       $("#submit_button").data("confirm", "foo");
    } else if(selected == 'false') {
        $('#fee').hide();
        $("#submit_button").data("confirm", "bar");
    }
```

This will change confirm message to foo if button selected is true, and bar if button selected is false. However, **what if I want to return nothing (no message), if radio button by default is true, and selected is true?**

Comment: according to your requirement I can say Use Checkbox instead of radio button.

Comment: `defaultChecked` DOM node property would return if input was checked or not by default. Now, reading 3 times your question, i'm still not sure what you are expecting here???

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do but your validation should be performed on submit click. On submit go and look for the input value and validate, if you value is X do Y if not Z. No need to set an event on the radio input.

Comment: Ok. Let me explain again. For example I have 2 radio buttons which will return true or false. If I set from false to true, and click on submit button, I need it to pop a confirmation message saying "foo", and if the other way round, it will alert a message saying "bar". Now my problem is, what if I don't want any message if the default value is "true", and when I click on submit, it is still "true". Is this achievable by jquery itself? @A.Wolff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start a variable outside the event:

```
var radioChanged = 0;
```

And, in your event increase it:

```
$(':radio').change(function() {
    radioChanged += 1;
    // your code ...
});
```

Then, later on:

```
if (radioChanged > 0) {
    alert('Change function occurred ' + radioChanged + ' times.');
} else {
    alert('Radio button not changed.');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I think there is a problem here. If users set from true to false, and false to true, It will alert `Change function occurred`. My condition is that  if radio button value has not changed when I click on submit, then it will return `radio button not changed`. Is this achievable in jquery or I am in the wrong direction? Thanks again

Comment: You can check `if (radioChanged % 2 == 1)` then the value is not the original one.

Answer (score 1):

As i understand your expected behaviour, check if any radio has no more its default checked value:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
  var anyRadioChanged = !!$(this).find('input[type="radio"]').filter(function() {
    return $(this).is(':checked') != this.defaultChecked;
  }).length; // '!!' to get boolean but it doesn't really matter here

  if(anyRadioChanged) {
     // show message(???)
  }
})
```

Comment: I didn't know about `this.defaultChecked`, nice one... but would it work if `defaultChecked` is meant by some sort of database call before the event?

Comment: @user6188402 `defaultChecked` is set according to how checked property was set the first time it is parsed by browser parser engine.

Answer (score 0):

you can hide message element just adding display: none to it or use jquery hide method

```
$('#someElementId').hide();
```

or

```
$('#someElementId').css("display","none")
```